# Running a Github Actions workflow only on events in a pull request events that change files matching a path

Tags: github-actions

I currently have a Github Actions workflow setup with the following trigger:

```
on:
  pull_request:
     paths: 
       - 'myFolder/*.yml'
```

I want this workflow to run on pull request events where a file matching with `myfolder/*.yml` has been changed. While this workflow does run on pull request events where this file has changed, it also runs on subsequent events even if they do not make any further changes.

The workflow this trigger is for runs a process using configuration from within the yml files and so if no changes happen to any of these files between commits (even if other files that do not match the filter are changed), the result will always be the same and does not need to be run.

I looked through the documentation for Github Actions and could not find anything that exactly matches my situation so would appreciate some help and pointers.

A simplified version with some name changes of the full workflow yml is:

```
name: Read yml files
on:
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - 'myFolder/*.yml'
jobs:
  promote:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    name: Read files

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Read
        run: npm run read-yml
```

Comment: You can't achieve what you want using on trigger alone. You would need to check the paths used on a step. I suggest using a [paths-filter action](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter#:~:text=README.md-,Paths%20Changes%20Filter,deployments%20only%20for%20changed%20components.) to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the action! I assumed that would be the case  but wanted to check!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do on YML workflow level.

You can however detect your case and leave early from a workflow.

I can suggest using [changed-files](https://github.com/tj-actions/changed-files#outputs) action:

```
- name: Get changed files
  id: changed-files
  uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v17.2

- name: List all added files
  run: |
    for file in ${{ steps.changed-files.outputs.added_files }}; do
      echo "$file was added"
    done
```

or you can use `renamed_files`, `deleted_files` if it fits better to your needs.

Then you can detect if there are any files that may trigger your generation action - if not, simply end the workflow.

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz, I assumed that would be the case and appreciate sharing the action. I'll look to incorporate this into my workflow!